# How to put complete vertical lines in Tables

Tags: tables

I have made this table for latex and placed 1 vertical line in it but this line is discontinuous i want this vertical line to meet with the horizontal line my code is

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{cc|cccc}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Sr. No.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Parameter}} & \textbf{Number} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D} \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{2}[1]{*}{1} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{A} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{2} & 0     & 0    \\
          &       &       & 0     & 0    \\
    1     & B & 2     &  5   & 7     \\
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please always post a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Avoid vertical lines when using `booktabs`...

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

Using vertical lines with `booktabs` is not recommended at all.

Excerpt from the documentation:

> [image]

If you want to "separate" the first two columns from the others, I suggest you to use `\cmidrule` as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}\label{tab:addlabel}
    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Sr. No.} & \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Number} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-5}
    \multirow{2}[1]{*}{1} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{A} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{2} & 0     & 0    \\
          &       &       & 0     & 0    \\
    1     & B & 2     &  5   & 7     \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Also note that the `\label` must immediately follow the `\caption` command.

Comment: i have much complex tables where i am using toprule, bottomrule, midrule, cmidrule so using booktabs is necessary is there any package which can remove the spaces in vertical lines created by booktabs package?

Comment: @Shaggi3 - The short answer is, "No". Do read the user guide of the `booktabs` package: The package's author leaves no doubt that he believes strongly that the use of vertical rules in a well-designed table can have no valid justification. It is with this design principle in mind that the details of `\toprule`, `\midrule`, etc macros were chosen. Short of undertaking a very major (and, in my view, utterly undesirable) hack of the `booktabs` package, one cannot obtain uninterrupted vertical lines in a tabular-like environment. By the way: *Why* are you trying to use vertical lines at all?

Comment: @Shaggi3 I completely agree with Mico. If you don't want to follow our advice, you can use `\midrule\addlinespace[-.5pt]` but I don't recommend it at all.

Comment: ok i guess the best solution here might be to remove the vertical lines @Mico